# How can I preserve empty MASTER branch in order to be able to checkout and switch back from other branches?

Tags: git, github

I am writing some python script which for new branches downloads the content from some old SCM system (migration activities).
I want to be able to `checkout` from `master` branch to that new branch, download the content to the new branch and then switch back to master branch. **Please be aware that MERGE to `master` branch should not be performed at all!!!**. I am executing all commands through the exec_cmd method which executes commands on the linux server.

Steps:

- `git clone` repo manually on the server
- execute script to create tmp file so that master is not empty
  `exec_cmd(['touch', 'tmp.txt'])`
- checkout to new branch `exec_cmd(['git', 'checkout', '-b', 'newBranch'])`
- download some files and folders using the custom logic...
- try to return to `master` branch with `git checkout master` - **FAILS!!!**

  `exec_cmd:`

  `['git', 'checkout', 'master']`
  `ERROR: command "git checkout master" failed with return code 1`
  `Command output:error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git`

What is the proper way to handle this this using the commands ( **without** `merge` and without `git login` through the script!)? I need to return back to master because from it again I need to create new branches for some other content so I need it to be empty (or almost empty with one tmp file which I thought will provide me a solution)!

Thanks

Comment: A branch with no commits doesn't exist. If you want an "empty" master branch that persists when you switch to other branches, make an empty commit on that branch (`git commit --allow-empty -m 'This is just a placeholder'`).

Comment: @larsks thanks for your assistance! I have only 2 more questions: 1. should I create tmp file before this `allow empty commit`  or this is  not needed? 2. since I need multiple branches to be created from master - is there some way that I can do this command only once in order to avoid repeating this commit? or there is no harm if I repeat this multiple times? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @larsks It seems something is wrong with this! So I did the commit which you suggested on master branch, then I did the logic on different branch and then when I checked out back to master - I can see the files and folders from different branch but I want to master be empty! `['git', 'checkout', 'master'] Switched to branch 'master'  $ git status On branch master Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone.   (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)  Untracked files:   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)    .accurev/   base/`

Comment: @VeljkoSbbb: in the future please [edit] your question to add details like this, because it's pretty hard to read text like this in the comments.

Comment: I have put a picture - I am not sure what I am doing wrong... why my master contains files since I checked out back only after I did all commits in my new branch... I want to keep it empty.. adding the picture https://cdn.imageupload.workers.dev/gKUgDbdR_output1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fundamental misunderstanding is here:

> execute script to create tmp file so that master is not empty exec_cmd(['touch', 'tmp.txt'])

In git, a branch does not contain files, it contains *commits* (or, more accurately, it *points at* commits). A commit *does* contain files - specifically, a snapshot of all the files in the repository. A commit doesn't have to have any *new* files, in fact it doesn't have to have any files in it at all, as "the repository at this point was empty" is a piece of information you can record.

The other confusion is that you seem to be trying to do this *repeatedly*, but once a branch exists, you can get back to it whenever you want. So you can create an empty master branch *once*, and simply switch to it each time.

To set up, as larsks suggested in the comments, you can run `git commit --allow-empty -m 'This is just a placeholder'` Or you could create a file and commit that, or anything you like really. Then in your script, `git checkout master` will return to that commit.

It's important to point out that `git checkout` will only change the state of files that are listed in one or both of the commits it's switching between. If you just create a file, it will be "untracked" - not part of any commit yet - and switching branch won't touch it.

Finally, to re-iterate: a branch does not contain files, it contains commits. So having created a branch in your script, you will need to commit something on that branch, otherwise as far as git is concerned that branch still just points at the same thing as master.

Comment: It seems something is wrong with this!
So I did the commit which you suggested on master branch, then I did the logic on different branch and then when I checked out back to master - I can see the files and folders from different branch but I want to master be empty!
`['git', 'checkout', 'master']
Switched to branch 'master' 
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .accurev/
        base/`

Comment: @VeljkoSbbb The key word in that output is "untracked" - you've created a bunch of files, but you haven't *committed* them anywhere. They're not part of any commit, so they're not part of any branch. This is what I was trying to say with the section in parentheses at the end of the answer; I've expanded it into two new paragraphs.

Comment: I did the commit in my new branch before I switched back to master.
https://cdn.imageupload.workers.dev/gKUgDbdR_output1.png
Please take a look
What am I doing wrong then since master also contains files although I have been adding the files only on newly created branch?  can you please double check? Thanks a lot

Comment: @VeljkoSbbb That image URL is broken, but if it's saying the same as in your last comment, then as I say, the key word is "untracked". An untracked file is not part of the current branch, or any branch; it is a file you've created, but not told git about; switching branches has no effect on it, unless there is a tracked file with the same name in the branch you're checking out. It might be worth spending some time using git yourself on the command-line, and getting the hang of the key concepts, before you carry on with this automation.

Comment: aha! I understand now what happened! I did commits for all the files but for the parent root folder itself it hasn't be added to the commit as well as the ignore file... that is why these items appear in master...  https://imageupload.io/i/smK9nblQKO I am marking the answer

Comment: sorry @IMSoP one more thing if I may - how I can execute `git commit --allow-empty -m 'This is just a placeholder'` only once? How I can check if I already did it in master so I do not do it multiple times - every time when I am switching to another branch from master? Because, as I mentioned it's easy if you do it manually, but I am making automation so I would like to optimize to do this placeholder commit only once. Can I achieve this as well with some command that will check if I already did that empty commit on master before? if not I suppose I will have multiple those empty commits

Comment: @VeljkoSbbb I'm not entirely clear what your procedure is, but you say you already do a `git clone` manually, so can you not do it manually then? Or, indeed, push it to whatever central repo you're cloning from? You'd only need to do it automatically if you were creating a completely empty repository each time with `git init`, and in that case you'd already need logic to know whether to run `git init` or not.